# What is objects synchronisation overhead?

Tags: java

I'm reading an Algorithms book using Java as the working language and the author states that the memory needed for each object consists of memory needed to describe each primitive instance variable and overhead (and padding).

Overhead consist of reference to object's class, garbage collection information and `synchronisation data`. I get the first 2, but have no idea what information comprise synchronisation data.

From google, I dedduced that this has to to with multithreading, but not much more. So what exactly is synchronisation data of an object.

Comment: Might be referring to semaphores

Comment: Every Object can be locked using a `synchronized(obj) { ... }`.   This is even implicit if a method is marked as synchronized.  Which thread holds the synchronization lock is important, because the same thread can enter a synchronized block multiple times.  So each object needs to store which thread has locked it, as well as (depending on how it is implemented) how many times.   Unless you are implementing or modifying the JVM, you will never need to the know the specific details.  Knowing that overhead exists, and perhaps its size, should be sufficient.